# How to make a field mandatory based on multiple fields

Tags: apex, soql, community, validation, validation-rule

I have 6 fields, 3 of which are picklist and 3 of which are text fields. If any of these fields are *not* null or blank, I want make another filed mandatory.

I tried a validation rule with or condition.It didn't work.please suggest any solution

```
OR(NOT(ISBLANK(unit__c)),NOT(ISBLANK( Activation__c )),NOT(ISBLANK(  
   Device__c )),NOT(ISPICKVAL(Unit_Price__c,"") ),NOT(ISBLANK(Fss_Reasons__c )))
```

Comment: Hey sorry i forgot to close the answer.Once again thanks for sharing knowledge.@Adrian Larson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check that the field you want to be "required" is actually blank in the instance that any of those fields are populated.

```
AND(
    ISBLANK(MandatoryField__c), // MISSING
    NOT(AND(
        ISBLANK(Text1__c), ISBLANK(Text2__c), ISBLANK(Text3__c),
        ISPICKVAL(Picklist1__c, ""), ISPICKVAL(Picklist2__c, "")
    ))
)
```

Comment: But what happens.When i try to create any opportunity with out any details of the above field.It throws an error @Adrian Larson .Means  i don't want a field to be mandatory  if all fields are blank

Comment: Wait, what? It should be mandatory if any are blank, except if they all are blank?

Comment: I need that field to be mandatory.If any field have value. @Adrian Larson

Comment: Okay...you could make your OP more clear...

Comment: Hey sorry my bad i didn't even work on it. thanks for sharing knowledge. @Adrian Larson

Comment: I edited formula a bit to make it cleaner: `AND(
    ISBLANK(MandatoryField__c), // MISSING
 NOT(
  AND(
   ISBLANK(Text1__c), ISBLANK(Text2__c), ISBLANK(Text3__c),
   ISPICKVAL(Picklist1__c, ""), ISPICKVAL(Picklist2__c, "")
  )
 )
)`